# Use EC2 to Zip S3 files

Tags: php, zip, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

I am trying to use EC2 to zip up some files that are stored in an S3 bucket. I have gotten as far as successfully getting SWFUpload to work with PHP and upload the files to S3. I read that the best way to zip up S3 files without incurring huge transfer costs is to use EC2 to deal with S3. After a lot of effort I managed to get a EC2 server running and SSH into it, but now I don't know what to do from here.

What's the best way to zip S3 files and put them back in the bucket?

Ideally, a user's batch upload would trigger an SQS and then I'd spin up the EC2 server once a day to zip them all and hand them back to S3 for downloading. No idea where to go from here. Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You should check out [aws](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=739) - a command line tool to ec2, s3 and other AWS services.

When you install the tool and setup your AWS credentials, it will create handy symlinks all kinds of commands -- including s3.

The general idea is:

- download the file from the bucket (`s3get <bucket/file>`)
- zip it (`gzip <file>`)
- upload it again (`s3put <file>`)

Let me know if you need more pointers.

Maybe you want to zip the file in PHP before you upload them? This requires the [zip](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) extension to be installed.

```
sudo pecl install zip
```

Here is an example script:

```
<?php
$zip      = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "/tmp/" . time() .".zip";
if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}
$zip->addFile('/path/to/uploaded/file');
$zip->close();

// continue uploading to s3
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to download the file from S3?